# Restrict a user from creating more than 'n' customers in Django admin

Tags: django-admin

In Django admin, how can I restrict a user from creating more than 'n' customers?

Comment: Count how many they've created so far, then just don't let them create.

Answer (score 0):

if `customer` is added to the main model as an `InlineModel`, then you just need to specufy `max_num` property ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.max_num)).

If this is a main model (not inline), the simplest is IMHO to override ModelAdmin's `save` method and check if adding additional customer is allowed.